# Discord JS - AudioPlayerStatus

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Why does this function:

```
client.player.once(AudioPlayerStatus.Idle, () => {
            console.log(client.playlist);
            next.run(message, args, client);
            client.playlist.shift();
            return;
        });
```

is executed only when the resource already played, and not when I initialize AudioPlayer? Isn't it by default idle?

Comment: I think it is by default "buffering" not "idle" but i'm not sure tho', maybe the status switches when the audio resource gets affected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the @discordjs/voice documentation ([reference here](https://discordjs.guide/voice/life-cycles.html#life-cycles)):

> Both voice connections and audio players are stateful, and you can subscribe to **changes** in their state as they progress through their respective life cycles.

The AudioPlayer starts in Idle, but do not trigger this kind of event because these events are only triggered when changing states.

That's why you can see the event firing only when resource already played.